# When call beforeUpdate method in Sails models?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I go by sailscast
I create in User model

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        login: {
            type: 'string',
        },

        password: {
            type: 'string',
        },

        birthDate: {
            type: 'date',
        }
    },

    beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
        //someCode();
    },

    beforeUpdate: function(values, next) {
        console.log("i\'m here!");
        if (values.birthDate && _.isNaN(Date.parse(values.birthDate))) {
            console.log(values.birdDate);
            return next({err: ["Wrong date!"]});    
        }

        values.birthDate = Date.parse(values.birthDate);
        next();
    }
};
```

I want change string value on date value in beforeUpdate method, but this method is not called.
may be i must call it by hand?

Comment: show us how do you update record in your controller, pls

Comment: `code update: function(req, res, next) {
  User.update(req.param('id'), req.params.all(), function userUpdated(err) {
   if (err) {
    req.session.flash = {
     err: err
    };

    res.redirect('/user/edit/' + req.param('id'));
   }
   else
    res.redirect('/user/show/' + req.param('id'));
  });
 }`

Comment: Try to change `User.update` to `User.updateById`

Comment: sory. do not understand how to use markdown

Comment: No problem. Welcome to community. You can not break lines in comments. Better to update your post in such situations

Comment: error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
 TypeError: Object #<bound> has no method 'updateById'

Comment: This is my mistake, sorry )) Add your code snippet to question and, pls, console.log what is the value of req.param('id') and req.params.all()

Comment: 54ea491055d0950d2803286f
{ login: 'losaped',
  email: 'losaped@gmail.com',
  birthDate: '14.08.1984',
  country: '',
  city: '',
  id: '54ea491055d0950d2803286f' }
"E_VALIDATION"
400
"1 attribute is invalid"
"User"
{"birthDate":[{"rule":"date","message":"`undefined` should be a date (instead of \"14.08.1984\", which is a string)"}]}

Comment: don't call exactly beforeUpdate method. I set console.log() on start this method, but output is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `beforeUpdate` method executes never because you have validation error.

`birthDate` should be date but sails get string and stopped updating process.

So, you should transform it to date before model's record is validated (and you try to do before it is updated);

Just rename your `beforeUpdate` method to `beforeValidate`. This should probably help.

You can find order in which sails executes model's lifecycle methods [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html).